# React component that returns on true will only accept styling via inline styles

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm attempting to style a Hover component while also adding animation to have it fade into view. I was going to use react-spring for the fade, but need to pass that as an argument to the style prop on the element.

I was originally styling the hover component with an inline styling variable, so in order to make room for the react-spring styling I moved the element styling to an scss module, and imported the module. But for some reason, the div that appears on mouse enter doesn't seem to be styled by the scss module. So I then attempted to use styled components, and for some reason the styled components aren't picking up the styling either. The code is as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import useHover from '../../hooks/useHover'
import styled from 'styled-components'




export default function Tooltip ({ text, children}) {
const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
`

const Info = styled.div`
  box-sizing: 'border-box';
  position: 'absolute';
  width: '160px';
  bottom: '100%';
  left: '50%';
  margin-left: '-80px';
  border-radius: '3px';
  background-color: 'hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9)';
  padding: '7px';
  margin-bottom: '5px';
  color: '#fff';
  text-align: 'center';
  font-size: '14px';
`
 const spring = useSpring({opacity: 1, from: {opacity: 0}})

 const [hovering, attrs] = useHover()

 return(
     <Container {...attrs}>
         {hovering === true && <Info>{text}</Info>}
         {children}
     </Container>
        
    )
}

Tooltip.propTypes = {
    text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}
```

The styling only seems to actually apply when I use inline styling variables. My only idea would be that it may have something to do with the reliance on the hovering state. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I read this and can probably help, but I'm not really clear on what the exact issue is. Can you try to clarify your post?

Comment: @Slbox My issue is that the styles aren't applying with styled components or with an scss module and importing to the element className prop. The only way that styling is actually applying to the element is through inline styling variables, as in, I create a const called `styles` and apply the styling to that, and call the variable under the `style` prop of the element. However, I need access to that style prop for react-springs, so I'm trying to free up that prop by using styled components or scss module file imports, but neither of those seem to be applying the styles.

Comment: Which styles specifically aren't getting applied? Is there a reason you're declaring `Container` and `Info` inside of your `Tooltip` function? In almost every case you'll want to declare them outside of the function, otherwise they get re-created on every render. If I had to guess, this is the problem.

Comment: I actually jsut figured it out, I have all of the styles in quotes for some reason, likely left from when I was messing with them in all sorts of different ways. I removed the quotes from around the Info properties and everything is now working as expected.

Comment: Oh yeah, that'll do it. Really easy to overlook and I've done it myself a number of times. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your time and efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issues was the quotes around the styled component values. Removed them, and everything worked as expected. I then just added the keyframes to the styled component rather than load the spring library for this component.